# FOL equivalence, operations and usage of quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'll start by saying that I searched for a discussion about this topic but I couldn't find the exact answers I'm looking for, so if you have a link to a previous discussion with the relevant answers I'll be much obliged.

I'm a student and I'm taking an intro course about mathematical logic (among other topics such as set theory and group theory). Recently we started studying FOL and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to properly use and write WFFs. The part I'm struggling with is how much difference is there between FOL and propositional logic when it comes to the behaviour of variables, quantifiers and logical operations. Mainly:

1. How much freedom do we have with the placement of quantifiers (while keeping them in proper order) in a given formula, and also how does this affect the logical operations we use. For example, are the following formulas equivalnet?
   $$\exists x \forall y \bigr(\lnot P(x) \lor Q(y) \bigr) \equiv \exists x \forall y \bigr(P(x) \to Q(y)\bigr) \equiv \exists x \biggr(P(x) \to \Bigr(\forall y\bigr(Q(y)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr) \equiv \biggr( \exists x \Bigr(P(x)\Bigr) \to \forall y\Bigr(Q(y)\Bigr)\biggr) $$
2. This is sort of a follow up to the previous question. How do I properly "translate" from english to FOL when describing specific definitions or sentences. Let's take the definition of a limit for example: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and let $L \in \mathbb{R}$ be a real number.
   We say that $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$, if for every $\epsilon >0 $ there exists an $M >0$ s.t. for every $x>M$ it holds that: $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. Honestly, I'm not sure I could write this down properly as a WFF. Is there a relation between the placment of quantifiers and variables to their dependency on other variables? (in this example, x is dependent on M which is dependent on epsilon)

Techincally there are still a few things I'm not 100% sure about, but first I want to clear this because I feel like until I wrap my head around this I shouldn't move on to bigger questions.

Thanks in advance to all who share their wisdom and time!

Comment: The rules for onversion into [prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) should help you answer part 1 for yourself. For part 2, the order of the quantifiers should match exactly your careful statement of the definition in English: $\forall \varepsilon (\epsilon> 0 \to (\exists M(M > 0 \land (\forall x(x > M \to |f(x) - L | < \varepsilon)))))$. It is customary to abbreviate this to $\forall \varepsilon > 0 (\exists M > 0 (\ldots))$.

Comment: Disclaimer: the answer to part 2 does depend on whether you are working in a first-order language that can usefully talk about functions as objects. If you are working in first-order set theory or some other strong system, then you can use first-order language to talk about the limit of some variable function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$. I suspect that that is not what you are looking for. If I am wrong, then you can use the approach of my comment to define a (partial) function $L$ such that $L(f)$ is the limit as $x \to \infty$ of $f(x)$, if that exists.

Comment: @RobArthan So just to be sure I understand everything so far:


1. The following equivalence holds as long as 'x' isn't a free variable in Q and 'y' isn't a free variable in P - $$\exists x \forall y \bigr((P(x) \to Q(y)\bigr) \equiv \exists x \Bigr(P(x) \to \forall y \bigr(Q(y)\bigr) \Bigr)$$

2. The issue with writing the limit definition stems from it not being a FOL formula?

Comment: For 1, you are exactly right. For 2, if you take the function $f$ as a given function symbol, then you can say in FOL in the language of real arithmetic what it means $f(x)$ to tend to a given limit. To say this for variable $f$, you need to work in a framework  that allows you to quantify over functions.

Answer (score 1):

For (1), the answer is yes (partially).
Since $(p \to q) \iff (\lnot p \lor q)$. En fact, this is true for any formula that if $\alpha$ was a sub-formula of a formula $\phi$, then obtaining a formula $\psi$ incurs if we replace one or more instances of $\alpha$ by some $\beta$; it follows that: $$(\alpha \iff \beta) ~ ~ ~ \iff ~ ~ ~ (\phi \, \iff \, \psi)$$ This is the called the *substitution theorem*. Here, us saying: $\exists x \; \forall y \; (\lnot \phi(x) \; \lor \; \psi(y)) \; \iff \; \exists x \; \forall y \; (\phi(x) \to \psi(y))$ is permissible.
"As for the third formula, this is wrong. Unless you say that: $\forall y \; \phi(y) \to \psi(x)$ when $\psi(y{\setminus}x)$ with $\lnot(x \in \text{free}(\psi))$, then that won't be true, and also no need for the quantifier anymore if it is not free. The same thing goes for the last formula too. (Thus, only the first one is logically equivalent.)", **the last paragraph is obsolete upon an edit to the question, for any reader, check the comments to get context, and an apt answer.** 

For (2), the answer will be given, and then some notes; here:
$$\forall \epsilon \; \bigg(\epsilon > 0 \to \Big(\exists N \; \big(N > 0 \; \land \; \forall x \; (x > N \; \to \; |F(x) - \ell| < \epsilon)\big)\Big)\bigg)$$
It is largely self-explanatory, although note the order of the quantifiers, and also that the greater than & less than signs are relations (constant predicates) which give out Boolean values (as opposed to functions, which gives out variables [terms]).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Just to clarify, in my first question I had a spelling error (I accidentally wrote 'x' insted of 'y' in the predicate Q) which is now fixed. Was that the problem? Or is it also because now the scope of the variable 'x' encases the entire formula and 'y' only encases part of the formula? If so, does this mean that once a variable is set to a certain scope, any changes to the scope will change the value of the formula?

Comment: @RONOLULU Yes. If it were to be the unedited version, then that would be assuming a substitution, and the explanation for doing the sub. the *right* way was given after. In that case, they would be equivalent if $x$ does not occur in $Q(y)$, and $y$ does not occur (or can be found) in $P(x)$. Because, if they were not, then in the 2nd formula it can be observed that they were quantified over, and removing them from the scope of each other changes their state from being bounded to being free, which is a no-no.

Comment: Take for example: $\exists x \; \forall y \; ((x = y \to y = x) \to (y \leq x))$, which if we do the same thing with as above: $\exists x \; (x = y \to y = x) \to \forall y \; (y \leq x)$ would obviously be different. Hope that made it clearer.

Comment: The notation involving $L_\infty$ that you have used on the left-hand side of your formula in your proposed solution to part 2 is not correct. The function that maps a function to its limit at infinity is not a first-order construct. The right-hand side of that formula is also incorrect (it implies that $\forall \varepsilon (\varepsilon > 0)$ which is false).

Comment: @RobArthan It is to map $F(x)$ to $\ell$ if and only if the right-hand side, it is not involved with any sort of infinite value nor infinite input (all given formulae & terms are finite). The '$\infty$' sign in the function is just notation and has nothing to do with what is written. For second point, I possibly could be wrong or perhaps en fact wrong but can you elaborate?

Comment: For the right-hand side, it should read (something equivalent to) $\forall \varepsilon(\varepsilon > 0 \to (\exists N \ldots))$, i.e., $\epsilon > 0$ is assumed not asserted. For the left-hand side, I'm afraid it just doesn't make sense: $F(x)$ is a value of the function, you can't define the limit as a function $L_\infty(F(x))$ of a single value.

Comment: @RobArthan Oh I see what is meant. I agree, the right-hand side will be fixed. Thank you. As for the left-hand side, I still don't get the problem. $F(x)$ is the image of $x$ under $F$, and it takes it as its value... If we put a regular limit, say $\lim_{x \to q} x$ it is unary if we take as a function. It's been noted as higher-order if taken at infinity, and I don't think so because there are no infinite formulae taken as input, nor terms. It simply takes the image of some value $x$ under the function. I'm sorry if I'm being annoying, I just still don't get where it goes out of FOL.

Comment: The operation that assigns to a function $f$, its limit $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $a$ is an operation on **functions** (regardless of whether $a$ is finite or infinite). FOL doesn't have function symbols that take functions as arugments. As you have written it, your left-hand side is applying your function $L_\infty$ to a value $F(x)$ and just says that $L_\infty$ is a function that is constant with value $l$ on the image of $F$. What you have written doesn't go outside of FOL, but it just doesn't say anything useful.

Comment: PS. but see also the disclaimer I have just added as a comment to the question.

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thank you very much! I just wanted to understand why. Sorry for any annoyance. I'll opt it out of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> We say that $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L$, if for every $\epsilon >0 $
> there exists an $M >0$ s.t. for every $x>M$ it holds that: $|f(x) - L|
> > < \epsilon$. Honestly, I'm not sure I could write this down properly
> as a WFF.

Not standard ZFC or FOL, but this may help:

$~~~~~~\forall f, L: [\forall a \in \mathbb{R}: [f(a) \in \mathbb{R}] \land L\in \mathbb{R}$

$~~~~~~\to [\text{ Lim}_\infty(f, L)\leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}: [\epsilon > 0 \to \exists M\in \mathbb{R}:\forall x\in \mathbb{R}: [x>M \to|f(x)-L|< \epsilon]]]] $

where $f$ is a unary function, and $\text{ Lim}_\infty$ is a binary predicate.

Or equivalently:

$~~~~~~\forall f, L: [\forall a: [a \in \mathbb{R} \to f(a) \in \mathbb{R}] \land L\in \mathbb{R}$

$~~~~~~\to [\text{ Lim}_\infty(f, L)\leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon [\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}\to [\epsilon > 0 \to \exists M: [M\in \mathbb{R} \land \forall x:[x \in \mathbb{R} \to [x>M \to|f(x)-L|< \epsilon]]]]]]]] $